# iphone - compiler conditional on header

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a project that generates applications for two targets.

One of the targets has to include one additional delegate protocol that should not be present on the other one. So, I have created a macro on Xcode and declared the header like this:

```
#ifdef TARGET_1
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
#endif

#ifdef TARGET_2
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
#endif

{ .... bla bla.... }
```

The problem is that Xcode is hating this "double" declaration of @interface and is giving me all sort of errors. When I put just one of the declarations the errors vanish.

How to solve that? thanks for any help.

Comment: Are use sure TARGET_1 and TARGET_2 won't be true at the same time?

Comment: yes, just one of them are true at one time

Comment: I discovered one weird thing, you have to have all PREPROCESSOR MACROS (release, distribution and debug) filled with your target name, even if you are not using one of them. In my case I was not using "release" and its preprocessor macros field was empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting a redecleration there you must have defined both symbols. Double check that your TARGET_1 and TARGET_2 defines aren't being defined together

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't hesitate to write something like:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate
#ifdef TARGET_1
, UIPopoverControllerDelegate
#endif
>
```

It looks ugly, but I believe it better reflects the semantics.

You can even do one better:

```
#ifndef TARGET_1
@protocol UIPopoverControllerDelegate
@end
#endif

@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
```

All of this doesn't invalidate the previous answers of course!